# Telegram webhook method requests for ssl3

Tags: ssl, nginx, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to configure my Telegram bot with webhooks. Using Let's Encrypt service I received certificate and when trying to open my webpage browser shows "trusted". After that I tried to activate Webhook, request was done by Postman. I received this [response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgqx7.png) from the Teleram server. But when I'm using **getWebhookInfo** method server sends me a message about [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UONve.png). But i'm not using **SSL3**. In nginx configs I found just **TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;**

P.S. I'm new to web programming, sorry if my question looks stupid.

Answer (score 0):

try set ssl for your site from http://cloudflare.com/
I think your ssl isn't safe enough.

you can set webhook with the below link:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<your_token>/setwebhook?url=https://addres_that_is_your_bot_code
```

example:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot382531162:AAGYSJSToS5r87ov7GecNwpCRIB515D3_uA/setwebhook?url=https://example.com/telegram/index.php
```

[KingRoot Apk](http://dlandroid.com/kingroot/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! SSL was fine, I found error in my own request to Telegram server. I made this [request](https://api.telegram.org/bot[TOKEN]/setwebhook/url=https://example.com:80). It was fatal error, anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: And this is right way how to make [request](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5BTOKEN%5D/setwebhook/url=https://example.com), cause in default configuration Telegram uses port 443